convert special time string to datetime format
The first dataframe can be convert to datetime format with pandas. The second dataframe missed some fields in input time string, what's proper way to covert the time strings to datetime object?
import pandas as pd

data = [
    '+2h03m46s456ms',
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ts'])
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], format="+%Hh%Mm%Ss%fms")
print(df)

data2 = [
    '0',
    '+456ms',
    '+46s456ms',
    '+3m46s456ms'
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['ts'])
#df2['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['ts'], format="+%Hh%Mm%Ss%fms")
print(df2)

Output:
                       ts
0 1900-01-01 02:03:46.456
            ts
0            0
1       +456ms
2    +46s456ms
3  +3m46s456ms


These are timedeltas, not datetimes. Use to_timedelta()
>>> pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(data))
0   0 days 02:03:46.456000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]

>>> pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(data2))
0          0 days 00:00:00
1   0 days 00:00:00.456000
2   0 days 00:00:46.456000
3   0 days 00:03:46.456000
dtype: timedelta64[ns]


But if you do want them as datetimes, you can add them to t=0.
>>> pd.Timestamp(0) + pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(data2))
0   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000
1   1970-01-01 00:00:00.456
2   1970-01-01 00:00:46.456
3   1970-01-01 00:03:46.456
dtype: datetime64[ns]


good answer! any api to convert the timedelta back to original string?

@lucky1928 Not that I'm aware of, but I haven't worked with timedeltas very much myself.
